# Issue with getting USB device permission from BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: java, broadcastreceiver, android-usb

I am using below code to get usb access permission from user when its detected, but it never get detected in android 11. Any help would be highly appreciated

```
public final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = "com.domain.ftd.USB_PERMISSION";

private final BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() { 
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


            if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION)) {
                boolean granted = intent.getExtras().getBoolean(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                Log.e("usb started","really");
                if (granted) {
                     //DO SOMETHING 
                }
         }

     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
             usbManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(this.USB_SERVICE);
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
            filter.addAction(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
            filter.addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED);
            filter.addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED);
            registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, filter);
    
    
    
    
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the broadcast receiver and call the requestPermission() method to display a dialog that asks users for permission to connect to the device,
please refer the [official doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host#kotlin)  and search for keyword "requestPermission()"

```
permissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE)
lateinit var device: UsbDevice
        ...
usbManager.requestPermission(device, permissionIntent)
```